# Как получить название самого последнего записанного ключа из файла json?

Tags: python, json

необходимо получить название самого последнего записанного ключа из файла json, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

С помощью json.loads преобразуем json строку в dict(словарь) и получим ключи.

```
with open("my_file.json") as f:
    a = json.load(f)
print(list(a.keys())[-1])
```

Но будьте внимательны, словари не упорядочены, можете получить не то что нужно.

Comment: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper - выводится такая ошибка

Comment: вы передали в loads не строковый json, а открытый файл. я подправил ответ, что бы было понятней

Comment: спасибо, так на много понятнее. Всё работает